# How to identify when the Android device was used last time

Tags: android, android-intent, service, alarmmanager

I am writing a piece of code in Android that will try to identify when was the last time the Android device was used by the user. By used I mean any operation performed. If the device is not used at all for lets say 1 full day I want to perform some action for it in my service which is running. So basically when the device is not getting used (idle state) that time I want to identify all this.

Is it possible in Android to achieve this? How can I proceed further for this requirement.?

Any pointers will be helpful to identify the device was not used for X days(or hours) and perform some action on it from idle state.

Thanks!

Comment: Would a broadcast event for `SCREEN_ON` (= usage) and `SCREEN_OFF` (= idle) be exact enough? Then check http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/ ...

Comment: Hi Trinimon,
Thanks for reply. Can we do processing while the device is in idle mode using service? Even if I use SCREEN_OFF broadcast event to mark starting of phone idle state but how will I find x time has passed from this point. Can we do processing in idle state of device in service?

Comment: You might do some processing in a service, yes you can. *Usage time* could be time from `SCREEN_ON` until `SCREEN_OFF` (you could store the timestamps accordingly - no issue). However, there are of course some aspects that makes it a bit fuzzy, just imagine: if the user puts the phone beside, it might still need some time until the display is switched off; or: if a user receives a call and he moves the phone to the ear, the display is turned off by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow [this tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) for screen turn On/Off. Hope it will helpful to you.

**How to identify when the Android device was used last time?**

When first time screen will turn on then you can read system current time  and save in shared preferences and from second time **(system current time - read last holed value in shared pref)** and convert these milliSec to time.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can we do processing while the device is in idle mode using service? Even if I use SCREEN_OFF broadcast event to mark starting of phone idle state but how will I find x time has passed from this point. Can we do processing in idle state of device in service?

Comment: My requirement is that I need to find time passed from last use of the device and perform some action when X amount of time has passed by. This does not mean device will be used at that time. I cannot rely on "screen on" to find the time difference and perform action.

Comment: Ok, In this situation you can you use alarm manager concept, you can set your X amount of time when screen will turn On, If screen will re-turn On before completing your X amount of time then you can re-schedule alarm manager otherwise you can trigger.